# Array remapping - Can I do this better?

Tags: php

for starters I have the following array objects (id, foo and bar are a result of a database query and should be addressed as object variables `->id`)

```
array([0] => array([id] => 1, [foo] => 'a'), [1] => array([id] => 2, [foo] => 'b')
```

and

```
array([0] => array([id] => 1, [bar] => 'b'), [1] => array([id] => 2, [bar] => 'a')
```

I want to create one new array with the id column as key

```
array([1] => array([foo] => 'a', [bar] => 'b'), [2] => array([foo] => 'b', [bar] => 'a')
```

I used the following lines of code to create the desired array:

```
foreach($array1 as $row1) {
   $newArray1[$row1->id] = $row1;
}

foreach($array2 as $row2) {
    $newArray2[$row2->id] = $row2;
}

foreach($array2 as $key => row3) { //array 2 is always longer or equal to array 1
    $result[$key]['bar'] = $newArray2[$key]->bar;
    if (isset($newArray1[$key])) {
         $result[$key]['foo'] = $newArray1[$key]->foo;
    } else {
         $result[$key]['bar'] = 0;
    }
}
```

I think this could be done a lot easier. Is this the case, if so, how?

Comment: A lot easier than these 7 lines of trivial code (a note: the code was changed not long after I've put my comment)? You could actually don't use an intermediate array and directly fill `$result` in the first 2 loops

Comment: isn't there something like array_merge that could do this?

Comment: If there was `array_merge_exactly_like_AgeDeO_needs()` function - then yes

Comment: ok, well, thanks for your help, if you answer with, "no there is not" I will accept it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you need to merge two arrays using as index the 'id' field, which is equal to both ones.
I would do this:

```
$newarray = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($array1);$i++)
    $newarray[$array1[$i]["id"]] = array($array1[$i]["foo"], $array2[$i]["bar"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of creating new array you can do this:

```
$arr1=array('0' => array('id' => 1, 'foo' => 'a'), '1' => array('id' => 2, 'foo' => 'b'));

$arr2=array('0' => array('id' => 1, 'bar' => 'b'), '1' => array('id' => 2, 'bar' => 'a'));
for($i=0;$i<count($arr1);$i++){
    $arr1[$i] = array("foo"=>$arr1[$i]["foo"], "bar"=>$arr2[$i]["bar"]);

}
print_r($arr1);
```